# connection pool between eclipse and tomcat for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

i'm trying to setup connection pool by tomcat.

I follow guide document at mysql page.

and that i run, i got error message that [javax.naming.NoInitialContextException]

here is my code, anybody have idea about that give me some advise! thank you.

I already include some jar file at web-inf/lib
as like : commons-collection.jar / dbcp / pool and mysql-connector!

this code in servers/tomcat/server.xml

```
<Context docBase="QuestionLogic" path="/QuestionLogic"
reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:QuestionLogic">
<Resource name="jdbc/test" auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
username="(myid)" password="(mypwd)" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://(mywebserver address)" />   
</Context></Host>
```

and then this is connection java class

```
public class DBManager {

public static Connection getConnection()
{
    Context initContext = null;
     Context envContext = null;
     DataSource ds = null;

     Connection conn = null;

     try {

      initContext = new InitialContext();
      envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
      ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/test");
      conn = ds.getConnection();
      System.out.println("connection suc!");

     } catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBManager.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: As you are having a `main` method, this does not appear to be a `tomcat` application.

Comment: even though i try use at tsp still get error message null pointerexception..
i can't not fix it , what's wrong my code.;

Comment: why do you think that a standalone application knows anything about tomcat's server.xml?